# Python, string imported with json.dumps() not recognized by if statement, why not?

Tags: python, json

I am as you may gather fairly new to this and am attempting to read through the a json file using a keyword to break at the last entry.

However the keyword `end` when read with `json.dumps()` is not recognized by an if statement so the loop never breaks.

Why not?

```
from sys import argv
import json
import time

script, filename = argv 
file = open(filename)    

jfile = json.load(file) 

currentIndex = 1

while True:
    now = time.time()            

    currentSegment = jfile[str(currentIndex)]        
    print json.dumps(currentSegment) #do stuff

    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
    waitTime = json.dumps(currentSegment['wait'])
    print waitTime
    if waitTime == "end":  #look for keyword "end", break loop. 
        print "break"
        break           

    waitTime = float(waitTime)  
    elapsed = time.time() - now  
    time.sleep(waitTime-elapsed)
```

And the json file looks like this:

```
{
"1" :   {
    "unit" : "feed.1",
    "time" : 500,
    "target" : 92.0,
    "wait" : 1
}
,
"2" :   {
    "unit" : "feed.2",
    "time" : 3000,
    "target" : 10.0,
    "wait" : 0.5
}
,
"3" :   {
    "unit" : "feed.1",
    "time" : 4000,
    "target" : 0.0,
    "wait" : 1
}
,
"4" :   {
    "unit" : "feed.3",
    "time" : 500,
    "target" : 180.0,
    "wait" : "end"
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting a string or integer to JSON *first*, then are testing against that. This means that there will be *quotes* in the value:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps('end')
'"end"'
>>> json.dumps('end')[0]
'"'
>>> json.dumps('end')[-1]
'"'
```

Using `print` shows you the string value with quotes too, that's because they are part of the value.

When testing you need to include those quotes *too*:

```
if waitTime == '"end"':
```

Better yet, **don't dump to JSON again**. You have perfectly good Python values here:

```
waitTime = currentSegment['wait']
if waitTime == "end":
    break    

elapsed = time.time() - now  
time.sleep(waitTime-elapsed)
```

Note that now you don't need to cast the `waitTime` value to a float again either; you can just use it directly with the `elapsed` value.

You only need to use `json.dumps()` if you need to send out JSON data to another system or save it into a file again. When working with the data in Python itself, there really is no need.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
waitTime = currentSegment['wait']
```